# Problem building relationships between models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Until now, I've been using acts_as_taggable_on plugin for tagging announcements.

That plugin creates the following tables:

taggings: relates tags and announcements table(for the tagged item, it has a field called taggable_id, which I rename to "announcement_id" for what I'll explain below).

tags: has the tag ids and names.

The other day, I discovered that I had no way of getting the announcements tagged with a certain tag, but doing `Announcement.tagged_with(tag_name)`, and I don't want to search by name, but for id.

So, as I'm using almost nothing of the functionality in that plugin, I decided to create the models for taggings and tags tables, to accomplish this: `Announcement.tags`.

The models' relationships look as following:

**EDIT:**

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :announcement
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :announcements, :through => :taggings
end

class Announcement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
```

Why can't I execute the command `Announcement.tags`? Because when I try, I get

> undefined method `tags'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've actually posted is that you've tried `Announcement.tags`. But `tags` would be a method on an `Announcement` instance, and that's calling it as a method on the `Announcement` class, which won't work.

Assuming you're actually calling `an_announce.tags`, you also need `Announcement` and `Tag` to have many `taggings` - like so:

```
class Announcement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :announcements, :through => :taggings
end
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try @announcement.tags, since tags is an instance method of Announcement class(model).

```
@announcement = Announcement.first
```

Comment: So, what if I wanted to get all the announcements tagged with a certain tag_id?

Comment: `Tag.find(tag_id).announcements`

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? You'll also need `Tag` to `has_many :taggings` - which I'll add to my answer.

Comment: I've edited my post with the updated code. It does not work when I do Tag.find(tag_id).announcements. It tells me "undefined method announcements" for that tag.

Comment: It works now! I deleted the plugin, and it seems to be working now. Thank you!